# How can I capture the Information output stream of a Job?

Tags: powershell, output, jobs

If I start a job, and that job outputs messages to the Information stream (or any stream for that matter), how can I capture that into a variable, or simply output it after I receive the job?

```powershell
$script = {
    [PSCustomObject]@{ "CoolProperty" = "CoolValue" }
    Write-Information "Returning a cool object" -InformationAction "Continue"
}

Start-Job -Name "test" -ScriptBlock $script | Out-Null
Wait-Job -Name "test" | Out-Null
$result = Receive-Job -Name "test" 6>&1
Remove-Job -Name "test"
```

The above code will output

```
Returning a cool object
```

to the console, but I would like to capture that and output it to the log file I'm using for the overall script, e.g.:

```powershell
$JustTheInfoStreamFromJob | Out-File "c:\file.log" -Append
```

I don't want to log the captured `$result`, because it also contains the Output stream (i.e. the object). I only want to log the Information stream. So I'm looking for a way to separate that out.

I see that there is an `-InformationVariable` parameter, but I don't understand how to use it, or if it's relevant for my question. I've tried a few methods of redirection, but I have very little idea what I'm doing when it comes to streams.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026972/capture-verbose-stream-from-job) gives me some hints, but not enough to understand.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973775/powershell-get-output-from-receive-job) is very similar but appears to have been asked before the Information stream existed. I'd rather not use Transcripts unless it's necessary; I feel like there should be a better way.

Some answers reference the `ChildJobs`, `Output`, and `Information` properties of a `Job` object, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to use them, as they are always null in my simple tests.

Thanks for your time.

## Solved

Thanks to @Santiago Squarzon and @Steven for two different working solutions:

```powershell
Remove-Job "test"
$script = {
    [PSCustomObject]@{ "CoolProperty" = "CoolValue" }
    Write-Information "Returning a cool object"
}

Start-Job -Name "test" -ScriptBlock $script | Out-Null
$job = Get-Job -Name "test" -IncludeChildJob # Steven's solution
$job | Wait-Job | Out-Null
$info = $job.Information # Steven's solution
$result = Receive-Job -Name "test" -InformationVariable info2 # Santiago Squarzon's solution
Remove-Job -Name "test"

$result
"---"
$info
"---"
$info2
```

This allows me to capture the job's output and the job's Info stream separately (two different ways):

```
CoolProperty RunspaceId
------------ ----------
CoolValue    f49c78bd-eda3-4c47-a6bc-d89a146618e9
---
Returning a cool object
---
Returning a cool object
```

Comment: Not entirely sure why would you do such a thing but for the sake of answering your question you need to redirect the information stream to stdout. Like this: `$job = Receive-Job -Name "test" 6>&1`

Comment: That is one of the solutions I tried (actually `*>&1`), however the issue is that this sends both the Output stream and the Info stream to the variable. I only want to log the Info stream, so I'm looking for a way to separate out the Info stream and log just that. Admittedly I did not make that clear in my code.

Comment: What do you mean by Output stream, what cmdlet there do you think is directing to Ouput stream?

Comment: I tried to update the question to make it more clear. Capturing the output of `Receive-Job "test" 6>&1` into a variable captures everything output by the job in both the job's Output stream (i.e. stream #1) plus the job's Information stream (#6). I'm trying to capture the job's Information stream separately. I apologize if my nomenclature is not accurate, I hope that makes sense.

Comment: You got it right with `-InformationVariable`, try `$result = Receive-Job -Name "test" -InformationVariable infoStream`. You'll see you'r PSCustomObject stored in the `$result` variable and the log in the `$infoStream` variable :)

Comment: Thank you. That worked. When I tried `-InformationVariable` before I made the classic mistake of specifying a variable (i.e. `$infoStream`), instead of a variable _name_ (i.e. `infoSteam`). Steven's answer also worked, once I got my order of operations correct.

Comment: Updated question with example solution(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different Streams are stored separately in the job object:

```
State         : Completed
HasMoreData   : True
StatusMessage :
Location      : localhost
Command       :  Write-Information "something"
JobStateInfo  : Completed
Finished      : System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
InstanceId    : ff5d1155-aca1-40fa-8e4e-dce6b87c709c
Id            : 2
Name          : test
ChildJobs     : {Job3}
PSBeginTime   : 4/2/2021 9:41:26 PM
PSEndTime     : 4/2/2021 9:41:26 PM
PSJobTypeName : BackgroundJob
Output        : {}
Error         : {}
Progress      : {}
Verbose       : {}
Debug         : {}
Warning       : {}
Information   : {}
```

Notice the child Job, but you can get at the information stream with something like:

```
(Get-Job -Name test -IncludeChildJob).Information
```

In the above example it will return "something", reference the command from the job.

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60180019/4749264) there's some other good information as well.

Comment: Thanks. This worked once I got my order of operations right. I needed to be capturing that before receiving the job, since `Receive-Job` removes that data. Or I suppose the `-Keep` parameter would have worked too.